# Decompiling 64bit ARMv8 Android .so library

Tags: ida, android, decompile, decompiler, libraries

I know IDA Pro can disassemble them to assembly code, but are there tools to decompile 64bit ARMv8 Android .so shared libraries to C?

Answer (score 4):

The first tool is IDA decompiler (a plugin for IDA).
As far as I know for now IDA has decompilers for x86, x64, ARM32, ARM64, PPC, PPC64, and MIPS (see [here](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/decompiler/) for more details, each of them costs additional money and should be purchased separately).

The second is [hopper](https://www.hopperapp.com/index.html) which has much weaker decompiler and claims to be able to decompile arm64.

There is also a new open source tool called [Ghidra](https://github.com/NationalSecurityAgency/ghidra) from [the NSA](https://www.nsa.gov/) ([Direct download link](https://www.ghidra-sre.org/) is unavailable from some countries, but VPN helps). It supports decompilation for a lot of platforms (because it uses the same intermediate representation for all processors) and as opposite to IDA its processor definitions are configurable and can be updated (see the [sleigh language manual](https://ghidra.re/courses/languages/index.html)).

The code generated by Ghidra may be less polished and less accurate, but you have a possibility, for example, to add new instructions when you need them - [see here an example](https://github.com/NationalSecurityAgency/ghidra/issues/78) (first I found, I'm sure there are more)

Comment: Sorry, I misread - you're right. Sadly there is no snowman support for ARMv8